# Angular change MatInput Size

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I am new to Angular 4 and started working with the material components, I copied a couple of example from the official documentation but didn't get the same result as the documentation : 
[image]

How do I get change the textbox width ?
I tried style="width: 200px;" style="width:100%"; class="col-md-x" 
But none of them worked, second thing is how to center that login container in the middle of the page ? I found a few answers here but none of them seems to be working as well, here is my code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <md-card>
          <md-card-title>Login</md-card-title>
          <md-card-content>
            <form class="example-form">
              <div>
              <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <input mdInput placeholder="Username" type="text">
              </md-form-field>
              </div>
              <div>
              <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input mdInput placeholder="Password" type="password">
              </md-form-field>
              </div>
            </form>
          </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
      </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To center in the container:

**CSS:**

```
.container{
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%; 
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
   width:100%;
  }
```

To style `matInput`( priviously `mdInput`) try one of these:

1. Use [::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep):

> Use the /deep/ shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force a style
>   down through the child component tree into all the child component
>   views. The /deep/ combinator works to any depth of nested components,
>   and it applies to both the view children and content children of the
>   component. Use /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep only with emulated view
>   encapsulation. Emulated is the default and most commonly used view
>   encapsulation. For more information, see the Controlling view
>   encapsulation section. The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is
>   deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools.
>   As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>>
>   and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader
>   compatibility with the tools.

**CSS:**

```
    ::ng-deep .mat-input-wrapper{
      width:400px !important;
    }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyzdvb)

---

2. Use [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation)

> ... component CSS styles are encapsulated into the component's view and
>   don't affect the rest of the application.
>   To control how this encapsulation happens on a per component basis,
>   you can set the view encapsulation mode in the component metadata.
>   Choose from the following modes:
>   ....
>   None means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the
>   CSS to the global styles. The scoping rules, isolations, and
>   protections discussed earlier don't apply. This is essentially the
>   same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.

**Typscript:**

```
  import {ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
  ....
  @Component({
        ....
        encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
 })
```

**CSS**:

```
.mat-input-wrapper{
  width:400px !important;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyzdvb-qtyhv6)

---

**3. Set styles in style.css**

This time you have to 'force' styles with `!important`.

**style.css**

```
.mat-input-wrapper{
  width:400px !important;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyzdvb-ynmh9y)

---

**4. Use inline style**

```
<mat-form-field style="width:400px !important" ...>
   ...
</mat-form-field>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyzdvb-twdmj2)**

Comment: Centering the container works perfectly, but not the mdinput's width, remains short :/

Comment: To which value you set? I set to 400px

Comment: I copied the exact same code to my global styles.css file, but it didn't change the width

Comment: Actually, deleting ::ng-deep in the selector did it !
.mat-input-wrapper{
  width:400px !important;
}
this works for me, thank you very much

Comment: ::ng-deep .mat-form-field{
  width:100% !important;
} also works

Comment: I created an id on mat-form-field in order for it to work for me

Comment: Why is it so much more complex to make an Input element wider than normal in Angular? Seems crazy you have to go to these lengths for such an everyday need. Why don't they just support a width attribute like HTML INPUT element?

Comment: @AlexBowyer, I guess they left us to customize with styling. Either of four solutions work separately. There could have been a width attribut on an mat-input though, which would easier to use :)

Comment: @Vega :: That is some pretty useful, helpful and informative stuff. How in the world did you find out about ::ng-deep? I am blown away. You just solved a few headaches for me. What else do you know? I mean, is there a source from which others could find out more about similar issues? Thank you.

Comment: Why is setting the width of an input so difficult in material? `::ng-deep` is deprecated :(.

Comment: A fifth way, branching from #4: Add a class to the mat-form-field and put the width !important on it.

Comment: I am new to stack blitz and I don't see anything show up in the side results. Is there some play/run button that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Micah, No it should run by itself. You can try to re-click on the top right arrow/refresh button on the right pan. Which of the demos are you trying to run ?

Answer (score 17):

[style.fontSize.px]=17 this attribute will change the size

```
<mat-form-field [style.fontSize.px]=17>
  <input matInput placeholder="Template Name" value="{{templateName}}">
</mat-form-field>
```