# How to increase/decrease mat-input and mat-select height?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to increase the height of the mat input to ensure all the input across the form is of the same height, as you can see in the attached image the drop-down is a bit larger. When I try to increase the padding of the input to increase the height alignment of the placeholder and arrow in the drop down inside the input isn't the center of the input like before. Can someone help me find the solution for the same? How can I increase the mat-input height to match that of drop down and other input components?

[image]

Comment: A similar question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502294/angular-change-matinput-size

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.